# Calculating percentages for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with the following structure

| index | candidato | Page Name | Post Created Date | Total Interactions | Likes | Shares | Comments | Love | Angry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | António Costa | Observador | 2022-01-03 | 4500 | 340 | 400 | 433 | 545 | 565 |

There are 9 different `candidato` (candidates) and 27 different `Page Name`

Full dataset can be found [**here**](https://github.com/JorgeMiguelGomes/LEG2022_MediaMonitor/blob/main/legislativas_2022_media_monitor_29jan2022/data_products/legislativas_2022_all_candidates_filtered.csv)

I need to find a way to calculate, for each `Page Name`, the totals and the **percentage** of `Total Interactions`, `Likes`, `Shares`, `Comments`, `Love`, and `Angry`
that will result in a DataFrame with the following structure

| candidato | Page Name | Total Interactions | Total Interactions Percentage | Total Likes | Total Likes Percentage | Other Columns | Other Columns Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| António Costa | Observador | 6500 | 34 | 23 | 1% | 540 | 23% |
| Rui Rio | Observador | 4500 | 23 | value | percentage | value | percentage |

The reason why I need to calculate this is in order to produce a **percent stacked bar chart** such as this one:
[image: Percent Stacked Bar Chart]

**What is the best way to achieve this with Pandas?** Thank you in advance for your help.

**Disclosure** This question is to help in a non-for-profit project that analyzes media behaviour, and bias, towards Portuguese candidates to the 2022 general elections. The [**prior report**](https://jorgemiguelgomes.github.io/LEG2022_MediaMonitor/) was made using Google Sheets but analyzing the datasets with Python is the best way, since I plan on doing this every 3 months.

The GitHub repo can be found [**here**](https://github.com/JorgeMiguelGomes/LEG2022_MediaMonitor), where you can access all datasets and code used.

Comment: how does "candidato" come into this? because what you explained omits it.

Comment: I will need to have to which ```candidato``` the values refer to, to use it as ```color``` for the Plotly Graph.

Comment: yeah, I understood how it relates looking at your plot. please see if my answer below works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` 'Page Name' and 'candidato' then find the sum of each of 'Total Interactions','Likes','Comments','Shares','Love','Angry' for each page name and each candidate: `totals`.

Then use `groupby` on `totals` by the first index level (which is "page name") and transform sum function so that you get the sum for each page name transformed for `totals` and divide `totals` by it to find the percentages.

Finally `join` the two DataFrames for the final outcome.

```
totals = df.groupby(['Page Name','candidato'])[['Total Interactions','Likes','Comments','Shares','Love','Angry']].sum()
percentages = totals.groupby(level=0).transform('sum').rdiv(totals).mul(100).round(2)

out = totals.join(percentages, lsuffix='', rsuffix='_Percentages').reset_index()
```

This produces a DataFrame that can produce the plot in the question.

Comment: Just a note: you have to add ```.reset_index()``` in order for the ```out``` dataframe to be ready to plot the Percent Stacked Bar visualisation

Comment: @JorgeGomes good point. I forgot it. I’ll edit it in.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the data via:

```
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JorgeMiguelGomes/LEG2022_MediaMonitor/main/legislativas_2022_media_monitor_29jan2022/data_products/legislativas_2022_all_candidates_filtered.csv
```

and reading in csv to dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv("legislativas_2022_all_candidates_filtered.csv")
df = df.drop(columns=["Unnamed: 0"])
```

You can groupby Page Name and sum the values in the columns you mentioned:

```
col_list = ["Total Interactions","Likes","Shares","Comments","Love","Angry"]
totals = df.groupby("Page Name")[col_list].sum()
```

The first 3 lines will look like:

```
              Total Interactions  Likes  Shares  Comments  Love  Angry
Page Name                                                             
Agência Lusa                4048   1464     285      1011    79    127
CM TV                      21813   7934    1050      7824   401    627
CNN Portugal              216437  59776    8755    107879  3640   5198
```

To get percentages, you can do:

```
percentages = totals/df[col_list].sum()*100
```

Sample from result:

```
              Total Interactions      Likes  ...       Love      Angry
Page Name                                    ...                      
Agência Lusa            0.324301   0.403282  ...   0.408945   0.371085
CM TV                   1.747521   2.185548  ...   2.075784   1.832048
CNN Portugal           17.339582  16.466265  ...  18.842530  15.188172
```